# using linq query to find value that differs from previously found value

Tags: c#, linq, sortedlist

Say i have a class that contains these items publicly accessible via properties:

```
class MyClass
{    
    int switch1; //0 or 1
    int switch2; //0 or 1
    int switch3; //0 or 1
}
```

This class represents switch states, and each time a switch state changes, i would like to add it to my transition list

I have a large sorted list that contains instances of this class and would like to use a query to capture only the entries in my list where the switch state for any switch changes.

Is this possible using a linq query?

Comment: you might want to look into the Reactive extentions library for C#

Comment: Just out of curiosity. If this is the whole class, what is your sorted list sorting on?

Comment: @alun - i have a uid that i create for other purposes.  This isn't the whole class, just the subset that is pertinent to my question.

Comment: An example could be helpful here.  When you say "previously found" do you mean previous item in the list in sorted order?

Comment: @James - If the first item in the list is 0,0,0 (the values of the switches in the class), then the query will return the record that has any of those values to be equal to 1.  I guess the simplest way i can explain it is that the first item in the list is my starting point.  Any time the value changes on any of the switches, return a record.

Comment: @Jason: so, correct me if i'm wrong, but you are getting new items every second, adding them to the list, and then querying the list to get the subset of state changes, correct?  The list ordering is temporal (as they come)?  At each query do you just want the subset since the previous query, or the total subset of all transitions?

Comment: @alun - Mario's example has an id as well, but i'm confused as to what purpose it will serve?  All the messages in the sorted list are the same type of message

Comment: @James - I am replaying data that has been stored.  I have read up all the data and split it into the individual lists.  This particular list has the switch states that we receive at 1Hz.  I'm not actually actively receiving messages.

Comment: Okay, but the rest is correct, right?  You want a collection of the transitions?

Comment: @Jason If messages have id's then you can find changes by just comparing the switches on items with the same id. If not then the question of how to tell if something has changed becomes completely different since it's not apparent what equal means. If we have [(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,1)] on the first pass and [(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(0,0,0)] on the next for instance did something change or not?

Comment: @James - Yes, i want the state transitions from the last state transition found.  I think the part that i was unclear on was that i want this to be a single query.  I am not looping and checking. I have all of my switch messages in my sorted list and i want to pair down to only those switch messages where the state has changed for any of the switches.

Comment: @Jason Do you mean that you have just the one list and want to eliminate duplicates? Something like this: [(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)] => [(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(0,0,0)]

Comment: Give my code a looksie below.  I think I have what you want.  Let me know if it's not and I'll tweak it.

Comment: @alun - That is what i'm going for.

Comment: @Jason It might be helpful to add something like that to the question so people coming in here late don't have to read all these comments:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

Assuming your class looks like:

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Switch1 { get; set; }
    public int Switch2 { get; set; }
    public int Switch3 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as State;

        if (other != null)
        {
            return Switch1 == other.Switch1 &&
                   Switch2 == other.Switch2 &&
                   Switch3 == other.Switch3;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I just added an `Equals()` to compare flags and my `Id` field is purely to demonstrate which items changed.

We can then craft a LINQ query like:

```
    State previous = null;
    var transitions = list.Where(s =>
                                    {
                                        bool result = !s.Equals(previous);
                                        previous = s;
                                        return result;
                                    })
        .ToList();
```

Not elegant, but it works, if you had this data set:

```
    var list = new List<State>
                {
                    new State { Id = 0, Switch1 = 0, Switch2 = 0, Switch3 = 0 },
                    new State { Id = 1, Switch1 = 0, Switch2 = 0, Switch3 = 0 },
                    new State { Id = 2, Switch1 = 1, Switch2 = 0, Switch3 = 0 },
                    new State { Id = 3, Switch1 = 0, Switch2 = 1, Switch3 = 0 },
                    new State { Id = 4, Switch1 = 0, Switch2 = 1, Switch3 = 0 },
                    new State { Id = 5, Switch1 = 0, Switch2 = 1, Switch3 = 0 },
                    new State { Id = 6, Switch1 = 1, Switch2 = 1, Switch3 = 0 },
                    new State { Id = 7, Switch1 = 0, Switch2 = 0, Switch3 = 1 },
                    new State { Id = 8, Switch1 = 0, Switch2 = 0, Switch3 = 1 },
                    new State { Id = 9, Switch1 = 0, Switch2 = 0, Switch3 = 0 },
                };
```

And ran the query, the list would contain your state transitions at items: 0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9

Comment: I believe this is what i am looking for.  Give me a few to implement it in my code and will get back to you.

Comment: Jason isn't segregating his messages by ID, each id is unique, so your example wouldn't match.

Comment: @James - I still have to do a bit of work to verify that the code is absolutely correct.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Jason: No problem, if you find an issue just let me know, happy to help!

Comment: @James - Finally got all the issues on my side figured out.  Everything works as in your example.

Comment: @James: you was assuming the messages are incoming always as an ordered collection, not as a stream (i.e. random arrival of messages).   How can you match the message pairs? This is the n-th case of question fuzzy explained (apart my non-native language)...never mind.

Comment: @Mario: I was just following the asker's need.  He indicated the transitions were in the list in order received and wanted the transitions between them.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follow:

```
class MyClass
{    
    int ID; //needs for recognize the message
    int switch1; //0 or 1
    int switch2; //0 or 1
    int switch3; //0 or 1
    public int Pattern
    {
       get { return switch1 + switch2 << 1 + switch3 << 2; }
    }
}
```

Then it must be declared a dictionary with the previous-state messages:

```
Dictionary<int, int> _prevStates;
```

each cell has for key the ID, and for value the "Pattern" of the message.
At this point, let's suppose that the new incoming message stream is a list of MyClass:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> incoming = ...

var changed = from msg in incoming
              where _prevStates.ContainsKey(msg.ID)  //what to do?
              where _prevStates[msg.ID].Pattern != msg.Pattern
              select msg;
```

Finally, you must update the dictionary with the changed patterns.

Cheers